# Does there exist a closed form for $L_k$ for any $k>3$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

I defined a sequence $L_k$ as the limit of a sequence of "hyperharmonic" series in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110017/question-concerning-the-divergence-of-a-kind-of-hyperharmonic-series-different).

I was surprised to find that $L_3=(\sqrt{13+4\sqrt2}-1)/2$, but was unable to find a representation for any $k>3$.

Does there exist a closed form for $L_k$ for any $k>3$?

Definition:

Let $H_k^{-1}=1$ for every positive integer $k$, and

$$H_k^r=\sum_{n=1}^k\left(\sum_{m=1}^nH_m^{r-1}\right)^{-1}$$

for every positive integer $k$ and non-negative integer $r$, so that $$H_k^0=\sum_{n=1}^k\dfrac1n$$ coincides with the usual definition of the $k$th harmonic number. I defined

$$L_k=\lim_{r\to\infty}H_k^r$$

Clearly $L_1=1$, it can be deduced from the continued fraction for $\sqrt2$ and the above definitions that $L_2=\sqrt2$, and I found the above value for $L_3$ with the use of high precision floating point.

Edit: I guess it's obvious that $L_k$ satisfies

$$L_k=\sum_{n=1}^k\left(\sum_{m=1}^nL_m\right)^{-1}$$

but I don't know how to apply this to calculating $L_k$. Wolfram Alpha was able to give me a hideous expression for

$L_4={\small-\dfrac{5+3\sqrt2+\sqrt{13+4\sqrt2}+\sqrt{26+8\sqrt2}-\sqrt2(361+178\sqrt2+51 \sqrt{13+4\sqrt2}+64\sqrt{26+8\sqrt2})}{2(1+2\sqrt2+\sqrt{13+4\sqrt2})}}$

Edit: I'm not so sure of this last sum. I believe I was given a correct result by Wolfram Alpha, but I think I might've made an error in transcription. Unfortunately I'm having a hard time getting the result again.

I put the simpler formula $L_k=\dfrac1{L_k-L_{k-1}}-\dfrac1{L_{k-1}-L_{k-2}}$ into Wolfram Alpha and it gave me the recurrence

$${\scriptsize L_k=\dfrac{L_{k-1}^2-L_{k-1}L_{k-2}+\sqrt{L_{k-1}^4-2L_{k-1}^3L_{k-2}+L_{k-1}^2L_{k-2}^2+6L_{k-1}^2-10L_{k-1}L_{k-2}+4L_{k-2}^2+1}-1}{2(L_{k-1}-L_{k-2})}}$$

which seems to work.

Comment: Can you add the definition here?

Comment: @Alizter I've added the definition.

Comment: $L_n$ already stands for Lucas numbers, use something else, like Ħ.

Comment: @TahirImanov I have no reason to expect that this is a sequence of general interest, so I see no reason to try to establish a convention for it, and it's quite clear that in this context $L_n$ doesn't refer to the $n$th Lucas number.

Comment: Have you already solved your question ? It seems to me that in your recurrence relation, there are only two occurences of $L_k$ : one on the LHS et one in a single denominator of the RHS. So $L_k$ satisfies a degree 2 equation, and thus can be expressed (although horribly) in terms of radicals involving all $L_j$ with $j<k$.

Comment: P.S. As to whether $L_k\to\infty$ : if $L_k$ has a smooth behaviour at all at $\infty$, then the recurrence relation suggests that $L_k \sim \sqrt{\log k}$. You can probably prove a lower bound by induction.

Comment: @Sary I know now that closed forms exist, but I don't know how to get to the equation you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $U_n := \sum_{k\leq n}L_k$ which is a simpler object. It forms an increasing sequence, and from your recurrence relation,
$$ U_n - U_{n-1} = \sum_{j\leq n} 1/U_j.$$
Assume that $(L_k)$ is bounded, say by $C>0$. Then $U_n \leq Cn$, and
$$ L_k = \sum_{j\leq k} 1/U_j \geq (\log k)/C $$
which is a contradiction as $k\to\infty$. You can probably tweak this to an asymptotic formula for $L_k$.

Comment: Excellent! How would I go about finding the degree $2$ equation you described in the comments?

Comment: You have $U_n - 1/U_n = U_{n-1} + \sum_{j\leq n-1}1/U_j$ : that gives you (after multiplying both sides by $U_n$) a degree 2 equation. Solve this in the usual way and you have an expression for $U_n$ in terms of a radical involving all $U_j$, $j<n$, which gives you inductively the closed forms you seek. You obtain $L_k$ by taking differences.

Comment: Can you see a way to adapt this to prove $(H_k^r)$ is divergent for all $r\geq0$? This is my previous, linked question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some additional information which could be helpful.

> Starting with OPs definition of $H_k^r$:
>   \begin{align*}
> &H_k^{-1} := 1\qquad& k\geq 1\tag{1}\\
> &H_k^r:=\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{H_1^{r-1}+\ldots+H_n^{r-1}}\qquad &k\geq 1, r\geq 0\tag{2}\\
> \text{and}\quad&\\
> &L_k:=\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}H_k^r\qquad&k\geq 1\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>   We observe according to (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> H_{k+1}^r&=\sum_{n=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{H_1^{r-1}+\ldots+H_n^{r-1}}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{H_1^{r-1}+\ldots+H_n^{r-1}}\right)+\frac{1}{H_1^{r-1}+\ldots+H_{k+1}^{r-1}}\qquad k\geq 1\\
> &=H_k^r+\frac{1}{H_1^{r-1}+\ldots+H_{k+1}^{r-1}}
> \end{align*}

Since $H_1^r=\frac{1}{H_1^{r-1}}$ and $H_1^{-1}=1$ according to (1), we obtain
\begin{align*}
H_1^r=1\qquad\forall r\geq 0
\end{align*}
and we get
\begin{align*}
L_1=1
\end{align*}

> We can now write a recurrence relation for $L_k$
>   \begin{align*}
> L_1&=1\\
> L_{k+1}&=L_k+\frac{1}{L_1+\ldots+L_{k+1}} \qquad k\geq 0\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   It's convenient to introduce 
>   \begin{align*}
> &S_0:= 0\\
> &S_k:=L_1+\ldots+L_k\qquad k\geq 1
> \end{align*}
>
> With the help of $S_k$ we can rewrite the recurrence relation (4) as
>   \begin{align*}
> L_{k+1}=L_k+\frac{1}{S_k+L_{k+1}}
> \end{align*}

We observe
\begin{align*}
L_{k+1}(S_k+L_{k+1})&=L_kS_k+L_kL_{k+1}+1\\
L_{k+1}^2+L_{k+1}(S_k-L_k)-(L_kS_k+1)&=0\\
L_{k+1}^2+L_{k+1}S_{k-1}-(L_kS_k+1)&=0\\
\end{align*}
and get
\begin{align*}
L_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(-S_{k-1}\pm\sqrt{S_{k-1}^2+4L_kS_k+4}\right)\qquad k\geq 1
\end{align*}

> Since $L_k$ is positive, we conclude with following *quadratic recurrence relation*:
>   \begin{align*}
> L_1&=1,\quad S_0=0,\\
> S_k&= L_1+\ldots+L_k \qquad &\tag{5}\\
> L_k&=\frac{1}{2}\left(-S_{k-1}+\sqrt{S_{k-1}^2+4L_kS_k+4}\right)\qquad &k\geq 1
> \end{align*}

With the help of (5) we successively find

\begin{align*}
L_1&=1\\
L_2&=\sqrt{2}\approx 1.4142\\
L_3&=\frac{1}{2}\left(-1+\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{2}}\right)\approx1.65967\\
L_4&=\frac{1}{2}\left(-(1+\sqrt{2})+\sqrt{19+4\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{2}}}\right)\approx1.8291\\
&\ldots
\end{align*}

> We can equivalently express (5) using $S_k$ only.
>
> We get from
>   \begin{align*}
> S_{k}&=S_{k-1}+L_k\qquad &k\geq 1\\
> L_{k+1}&=L_k+\frac{1}{S_k+L_{k+1}}\\
> \end{align*}
>   the equation
>   \begin{align*}
> (S_{k+1}-S_k)&=(S_k-S_{k-1})+\frac{1}{S_k+(S_{k+1}-S_k)}\\
> S_{k+1}-2S_k+S_{k-1}&=\frac{1}{S_{k+1}}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and finally
>   \begin{align*}
> &S_0=0,\quad S_1=1,\\
> &S_{k+1}(S_{k+1}-2S_k+S_{k-1})=1\\
> \text{resp.}&\\
> &S_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(2S_k-S_{k-1}+\sqrt{4S_k^2-4S_kS_{k-1}+S_{k-1}^2+4}\right)
> \end{align*}

The first values $S_k$, $1 \leq k \leq 4$ give in accordance with the numerical values from $L_k$ above
\begin{align*}
S_0=0,S_1=1,S_1\approx 2.41421,S_3\approx 4.07389,S_4\approx 5.90298
\end{align*}

*Note:* As far as I know, there is no systematic theory to solve quadratic recurrence relations similar to the theory we have for linear recurrences. I don't see a fruitful specific Ansatz to obtain a closed formula for $L_k$.

Observe that the expressions of $L_k$ grow in complexity with increasing $k$. Maybe in papers like [this one](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0802/0802.2565.pdf) you could find hints for studying some more aspects of quadratic recurrence relations. I don't adress the periodicity within this paper, but instead the fact that iterative solutions of quadratic equations are analysed.

Comment: Your last equation is essentially the same one Sary helped me find, since $2S_k-S_{k-1}=S_k+\sum_{n=1}^k\dfrac1{S_n}$, but yours is easier to write.

Comment: @JaycobColeman: Thanks. Good to see my answer is useful for you.